# Smart contract deployment error in Hyperledger Besu Network

Tags: ethereum, hyperledger, smartcontracts, hyperledger-besu

We have setup a network using QBFT consensus protocol having four validator nodes in our network. Now we are trying to deploy one sample smart contract in that network using public_tx script, but we are facing issue at the time of deployment.

```
Error: Returned error: Gas price below configured minimum gas price
```

This is the error that we are facing, although we have even tried with the free gas network configuration but even then we are getting this error only.

Can someone please help from the community in resolving this error?